# displaying an image in the GSP

Tags: grails

I;m trying to display an image saved in the DB as BLOB in GSP , but it doesn't show , here is my code :

Domain :

```
  class Photos {
   Date dateCreated
   byte [] photo
   Date lastUpdated

  }
   static mapping ={ photo(sqlType:"BLOB") }
 }
```

Controller:

```
def display()
{
    def photosInstance = Photos.get(1).photo  
    byte [] image =params.photos // byte array
    response.setHeader('Content-length', "${image.length}"
    response.contentType = 'image/jpeg' // or the appropriate image content type
    response.outputStream << image
    response.outputStream.flush()

}
```

GSP:

```
<g:each var="img" in="${photosInstance}">
<img src="${createLink(action: 'display', params:[photos:"${img}"])}">
</g:each>
```

this is the link:

```
http://localhost:8080/myApp/ads/display?photos=%5B65%2C+110%2C+100%2C+114%2C+111%2C+105%2C+100%2C+49%2C+46%2C+106%2C+112%2C+103%5D
```

here is the view :

[image: screenshot]

any clues ?

Answer (score 1):

This seems strange to me...

```
def display() {
    def photosInstance = Photos.get(1).photo  
    byte [] image =params.photos // byte array
    response.setHeader('Content-length', "${image.length}"
    response.contentType = 'image/jpeg' // or the appropriate image content type
    response.outputStream << image
    response.outputStream.flush()
}
```

I'd do this...

```
def display() {
    def photosInstance = Photos.get(params.id)
    byte [] image = photosInstance.photo // byte array
    response.setHeader('Content-length', "${image.length}"
    response.contentType = 'image/jpeg' // or the appropriate image content type
    response.outputStream << image
    response.outputStream.flush()
}
```

and then...

```
<g:each var="img" in="${photosInstance}">
   <img src="${createLink(action: 'display', id:${img.id})}">
</g:each>
```

Comment: photosInstance.photos should be photosInstance.photo, and there no listts in this class, so no loop is necessary

Answer (score 1):

```
def display() {
    def photosInstance = Photos.get(params.id)
    response.contentType = 'image/jpeg'
    response.contentLength = photosInstance.photo.size()
    OutputStream out = response.outputStream
    out.write(photosInstance.photo)
    out.close()
}
```

It seems that you have one photo property in Photos Domain so no need for the loop in the GSP, unless you have a list of Photos:

```
<img src="${createLink(action: 'display', id:photosInstance.ident())}">
```

Comment: tired as you showed , but still having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

You can try this with base64 encoding.

```
<img class="materialboxed" width="250" height="250" src="" name = "file[]" id="profilePic">
```

This will convert bytecode into base64. This code should be in change event of upload button.

```
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#profilePic').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
```

You can render image on ajax call.

```
 $("#profilePic").attr('src',data.uploadedImage);
```

Domain

```
   class PersonalInfo {
        String name
        String profilePic
        static constraints = {
            name nullable: true
            profilePic nullable: true
            profilePic(maxSize: 50000000)
        }
        static mapping = {
            profilePic type:"text"
        }
}
```